# OnChange event succesfully completes but renders other elements useless

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have been trying to fix this issue for the past 2-3 hours but finally gave up. This is part of my javascript/jquery.

```
$(function() {  
    $('#ob').change(function() {
       var id = $("#ob").val();  
       var form_data = {
           id: id,
           OB: 3 
       };

       $.ajax({
           url: "changeinfo.php",
           type: 'POST',
           data: form_data,
           success: function(data) {
               $("#finfoob3").html(data);                             
           }
       });

       return false; 
   });
});
```

The above successfully modifies a DIV element on change.

However in that DIV element, there was a button with id=obt3 which doesn't work. Actually, it was overwriting it's name to something else. I sent another POST value OB to the AJAX call and concatenate it with obt so that it becomes obt3. I then put the id of the button to obt3 but it still wouldn't respond to a click event.

I tried to inspect the element with google chrome and the element's id successfully changes to obt3 but wouldnt respond to it's click event.

Comment: What's your question here? Are you simply looking for someone to review your code?

Comment: Question is, when i trigger the change event of #ob, it modifies a div element called #finfoob3. Within #finfoob3, there is a button with id=obt3. Before triggering the on change event, obt3 works fine. Triggering it again, obt3 doesn't work since the div element is replaced. Still, i tried to rename obt3 within the replaced html but it wouldn't respond to obt3 click event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that when you replaced the contents of `#finfoob3` you destroyed all the nodes that lived there, along with all their event handlers.  There are two ways to handle this:

- After replacing the div contents, re-create any event handlers you need.
- Use [Event Delegation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687296/what-is-dom-event-delegation) to attach the event handlers to `#finfoob3`, so they won't be destroyed when you change its contents.

Since you are using jQuery, you should look at the [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.  It gives you an easy way to define event delegation.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
$(document).on("click", "#obt3", function() {
       //do whatever
   });
```

Here we're binding the document with all the dynamically created #obt3 elements.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your question. You have a div with id `finfoob3` and in this div you have a button with id `obt3` and you have an event click handler on this button, and you have another element with id `ob`, which change trigger call ajax and return some html code with a button `obt3`, which is same like button which you have previously, but now it is not responding to click event

and this obt3 event handler is something like this

```
$('#obt3').click(function(){ 
    //Some code which you want to perform
});
```

but it is not working so change it to

```
$('#finfoob3').on('click', '#obt3' ,function(){ 
    //Some code which you want to perform
});
```

and it will work as you want, but make sure you are using jquery version 1.6 or later.